# How to compare a value against multiple values in SET datatype

Tags: php, mysql

I have three different possible values stored in a SET datatype in my mySQL database. I need to know how to use PHP to check if a local variable matches any of the values in the set. I'm not sure how to do this since the SET isn't an array, and when i try to explode the result I get nothing.

Comment: First link found with google: http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/19/php-to-get-enum-set-values-from-mysql-field/

Comment: The function on the link works. Just replace split() with explode(). Once you have the array use in_array() as shmeeps suggested you.

Comment: See also [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, a set is stored like

```
data1,data2,data3
```

In which case you should be able to

```
$array = explode(',', $data);
```

Then you should be able to use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search it.

You do say that explode didn't work, just making sure you had it set correctly. If that doesn't work, double check that the data is set before you try to [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it.